# Getting sharp angles when using TracedPath in Manim Community

Tags: python, manim

I'm a beginning user of Manim and I'm using the `TracedPath` class. Here's the code for my scene:

```py
class scene (Scene):
    def construct(self):

        vt1 = ValueTracker(0)
       
        d = always_redraw(lambda : Dot().shift(np.array((2*cos(vt1.get_value()), 2*sin(vt1.get_value()), 0.0))))

        tr = TracedPath(d.get_center, dissipating_time=3, stroke_opacity=[0, 1], stroke_color=BLUE+GREEN)

    

        self.wait(.5)

        self.play(FadeIn(d, shift=UP), run_time=.2)

        self.add(tr)

        self.play(vt1.animate.set_value(2*PI), run_time=.4)
```

This is the last frame of the resulting video:

[The last frame of the resulting video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2O5B.png)

Because the `run_time` argument in the `self.play` method is set to 0.4 seconds, the path looks very sharpy. Is there a way to make it smoother? Anything would help.

I am using Python 3.10.7, Windows 11, Manim Community v0.16.0.